# Record ownership...dilemma

Tags: security, sharing

Suppose user A transfers his Records User B .Will user A still retain owership after transferring?

How can user A revoke access of Record from User B

Comment: Hi user666440, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is unclear. When you say "transfer", did ownership of the record change or did User A share a record with User B? Also, what's the sharing model for the Object Type for the record (Org Wide Defaults) and does User A own the actual record?

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose user A transfers his Records User B .Will user A still retain owership after transferring?

No. A record must be owned by exactly one user. Transferring a record's ownership revokes the *transfer* permission that is granted with record ownership. What happens after that depends on any other settings that may allow access to the record.

> How can user A revoke access of Record from User B

By default, A can't revoke access to B, because B now has Full Access to the record, and A may have diminished, or perhaps even *zero*, access to that record.

However, administrators could configure a number of options that could allow A to reclaim the record from B. These include the user permissions *Modify All Data*, access through the *role hierarchy*, changing the *organization wide defaults*, setting up *sharing rules*, enabling *territory management*, or even developing *custom code* that allows the user to reclaim records they normally can't.

In the most usual scenario, however, accidental record transfers must be fixed either by the user that received the record (User B, in this case), any other user that has same authority as B (e.g. if C, who is B's manager, is higher than B in the role hierarchy, and settings allow it, they could fix it), or a system administrator.